# Joining mutiple select statements in one SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, average

I am trying to join two sql statements into one but have had no success.

I would ideally like the Average query to be added to the end of the columns from the first sql statement.

**First statement:**

```
SELECT Modules.UserID, Module_Info.ModuleTitle, Modules.ModuleMarks, Modules.ExamMark, Modules.AssignmentMark, MarkClassification.MarkDescription
FROM Module_Info 
INNER JOIN Modules ON Module_Info.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID 
INNER JOIN MarkClassification ON Modules.MarkCodeDescription = MarkClassification.MarkId
WHERE(Modules.UserID = '8')
```

**Second statement:**

```
SELECT AVG(Modules.ExamMark) AS Average    
FROM Module_Info     
INNER JOIN Modules ON Module_Info.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID
WHERE (Modules.ModuleID = '2')
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a sub query in the select for that, like this:

```
SELECT Modules.UserID, Module_Info.ModuleTitle, Modules.ModuleMarks,
       Modules.ExamMark, Modules.AssignmentMark, MarkClassification.MarkDescription,
       (SELECT AVG(Modules.ExamMark) 
        FROM Module_Info 
        INNER JOIN Modules ON Module_Info.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID
        WHERE (Modules.ModuleID = '2')) as Average
FROM Module_Info 
INNER JOIN Modules
 ON Module_Info.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID 
INNER JOIN MarkClassification
 ON Modules.MarkCodeDescription = MarkClassification.MarkId
WHERE(Modules.UserID = '8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when i run the query you suggested i get the following: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT Modules.UserID, Module_Info.ModuleTitle, Modules.ModuleMarks, Modules.ExamMark, Modules.AssignmentMark, MarkClassification.MarkDescription
FROM Module_Info
INNER JOIN Modules ON Module_Info.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID
INNER JOIN MarkClassification ON Modules.MarkCodeDescription = MarkClassification.MarkId
WHERE(Modules.UserID = '8')) t1

JOIN

(SELECT AVG(Modules.ExamMark) AS Average
FROM Module_Info
INNER JOIN Modules ON Module_Info.ModuleID = Modules.ModuleID
WHERE (Modules.ModuleID = '2')) t2
```

Since you do not have a join condition, it will create a cartesian product of the two queries (i.e. each row of the first subselect, with each row of the second subselect). Since the 2nd subselect only has one row, it will give you your expected result.

Comment: thanks for the answer once i run it i get the following : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 't2'.

Comment: Try adding 'on 1=1' as an 'always true' join condition